# Evaluate phase of $X(\omega)$ without computing $X(\omega)$

Tags: discrete-signals, phase, dtft

$$x(n) = \{ -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1 \}$$

Let $X(\omega)$ be the DTFT of $x(n)$. I need to find the phase of $X (\omega)$ without computing $X(\omega)$. I notice that $x(n)$ can be a type I linear phase filter, but not sure if that is used in solving the problem.

Comment: You noticed correctly, so I guess the problem is solved, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: x(n) has symmetric coefficients which as a filter is a type 1 linear phase filter as the OP has stated. Such a filter will have a phase slope that is dependent on the number of taps only.

Comment: So my group delay is (N-1) /2 and I integrate w.r.t w to find phase

Comment: Yes that is true but it is even simpler than having to integrate- realize the phase for every unit sample delay goes from 0 to $-2\pi$ as the frequency goes from 0 to the sampling rate.